# A query in the proof of convergence of the set $\{1/n\}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I have a query regarding the proof of the statement that the set $S = \left\{ \dfrac {1}{n} \right\}$ has limit point $0$. I am studying an introductory course in Analysis.

**Proof:**

From the definition of a limit point, Let $X=\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R^p$. An element $x$ of $\mathbb R^p$ is a limit of $X \iff$ for each positive real number $\epsilon$ there is natural number $K(\epsilon)$ such that if $ n \geq K(\epsilon)$, then $|x_n-x| < \epsilon$

> Using the above statement, there exists a natural number $K(\epsilon)$, whose value depends on $\epsilon$ such that $\dfrac {1}{K(\epsilon)} < \epsilon$.
>
> I don't understand well the above line. Have they already assumed that $0$ is the limit point of $S$?

Could you please guide me on how they deduced the line shown in blue from the definition of limit point given above?

Comment: One does not usually say that a set "converges" (as you did in the title). It has limit points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the author means he is using the above statement then making an assertion to show that it is satisfied. The fact that given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a positive integer $N$ so that $N>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ follows from what is known as the Archimedean Principle.

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Archimedean_Principle

Comment: yeah, exactly.. I too was thinking on the same lines :-) .

Answer (score 1):

For a given $\epsilon > 0$, choose a natural number $K$ such that: $K > \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$, then we have: $\dfrac{1}{K} < \epsilon$. Thus if $n > K$, then: $\dfrac{1}{n} < \dfrac{1}{K} < \epsilon$. This shows that $0$ is a limit point of the sequence $\{\dfrac{1}{n}\}$

Comment: So that means, technically, the author has not used the above theorem in the way he has stated it. He has just used the archimedean principle. Am I right?

Comment: I think you are right.